# Why the variable height value is rest to 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum CircleHeight
    {
        Center, Bottom, Top
    };

    public CircleHeight circleheight;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 50)]
    public float xradius = 1.5f;
    [Range(1, 50)]
    public float yradius = 1.5f;
    [Range(-10, 10)]
    public float height = 0;
    public bool changeBothRadius = false;
    [Range(0.1f, 2)]
    public float lineThickness = 0.1f;
    public bool minimumRadius = false;
    public bool draw = false;
    public bool animateCircle = false;
    public float animationSpeed = 0.5f;

    private LineRenderer line;
    private Renderer renderer;
    private float Bottom;
    private float Top;
    private float Center = 0;
    private float t = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        circleheight = CircleHeight.Center;

        line = gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.LineRenderer>();
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        Bottom = transform.InverseTransformPoint(renderer.bounds.min).y + 0.1f;
        Top = transform.InverseTransformPoint(renderer.bounds.max).y + 0.1f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        line.startWidth = lineThickness;
        line.endWidth = lineThickness;

        if (draw)
        {
            line.enabled = true;
            CreatePoints();
        }
        else
        {
            line.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    bool animStart = true;
    void CreatePoints()
    {
        float x;
        float z;

        float angle = 20;

        if (animateCircle == false)
        {
            switch (circleheight)
            {
                case CircleHeight.Center:
                    height = Center;
                    break;
                case CircleHeight.Bottom:
                    height = Bottom;
                    break;
                case CircleHeight.Top:
                    height = Top;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AnimateCircle(Top, Bottom);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, height, z));

            angle += (360f / segments + 1);
        }
    }

    private void AnimateCircle(float From, float To)
    {
        if (animStart)
        {
            if (height == Center)
            {
                height = Mathf.Lerp(Center, From, t);
                t += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                if (height == From)
                {
                    animStart = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the animateCircle flag to prevent from the enum to reset the height to Center all the time:

```
if (animateCircle == false)
```

Then I added a breakpoint and it's not passing in again it's doing all the time the else part:

```
else
            {
                AnimateCircle(Top, Bottom);
            }
```

And I see that height value is 0.6 after doing the process inside AnimateCircle method.

But then I added a breakpoint also on the line:

```
line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, height, z));
```

First loop height is 0.6 but then after the loop end when i = 50 and the loop start over again I see that height is 0. But I'm not reseting height any where else.

This is the AnimateCircle method unused code just to show what I tried and means to do:

```
private void AnimateCircle(float From, float To)
    {
        // From = Top To = Bottom
        // height = Center

        if (animStart)
        {
            if (height != From)
            {
                height = Mathf.Lerp(height, From, t);
            }
            else
            {
                height = Mathf.Lerp(From, To, t);
            }
            t += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            if (height == From || height == To)
                animStart = false;
        }
        else
        {
            height = Mathf.Lerp(From, To, t);
            t += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            if (t > 1.0f)
            {
                if (To == Top)
                {
                    float temp = To;
                    To = From;
                    From = temp;
                    t = 0.0f;
                }
                if(To == Bottom)
                {
                    float temp = From;
                    From = To;
                    To = temp;
                    t = 0.0f;
                }
            }

            if (To == Top)
            {
                height = Mathf.Lerp(Bottom, Top, t);
                t += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

                if (t > 1.0f)
                {
                    float temp = Top;
                    Top = Bottom;
                    Bottom = temp;
                    t = 0.0f;
                }
            }

            if(To == Bottom)
            {
                height = Mathf.Lerp(Top, Bottom, t);
                t += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

                if (t > 1.0f)
                {
                    float temp = Bottom;
                    Bottom = Top;
                    Top = temp;
                    t = 0.0f;
                }
            }
        }
    }*/
```

For example the game start when the enum default state is Center in the Start.
And if I call `AnimateStart(Top, Bottom);` or `AnimateStart(Bottom, Top);`

Then inside AnimateCircle I want to move the circle from the Center to the Top or Bottom depending on how I'm calling it. So From can be Top or Bottom.

After the circle moved from the Center once to the Top or Bottom then start a ping pong nonstop between Top and Bottom (Or bottom top).

And if the game start with the enum default state as Bottom or Top then just start a ping pong between the top and Bottom without the Center.

EDIT:

This is the code for the AnimateCircle I'm using now:

```
private void AnimateCircle(float From, float To)
    {
        if (animStart)
        {
            // prevent t from exceeding tGoal
            if (t > tGoal)
            {
                t = tGoal;
            }

            // end animation when t reaches goal
            if (t == tGoal)
            {
                animStart = false;
            }

            // advance height according to t
            height = Mathf.Lerp(Bottom, Top, Mathf.PingPong(t, 1f));

            // advance height according to time & speed
            t += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

The CreatePoints didn't change:

```
    bool animStart = true;
    void CreatePoints()
    {
        float x;
        float z;

        float angle = 20;

        if (animateCircle == false)
        {
            switch (circleheight)
            {
                case CircleHeight.Center:
                    // t=0.5f, tGoal=1f to go to top first then stop at top
                    // t=0.5f, tGoal=2f to go to top first then stop at bottom
                    // t=1.5f, tGoal=2f to go to bottom first then stop at bottom
                    // t=1.5f, tGoal=3f to go to bottom first then stop at top

                    t = 0.5f;
                    tGoal = 2f;
                    height = Center;
                    break;
                case CircleHeight.Bottom:
                    t = 0f;
                    tGoal = 1f;
                    height = Bottom;
                    break;
                case CircleHeight.Top:
                    t = 1f;
                    tGoal = 2f;
                    height = Top;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AnimateCircle(Bottom, Top);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, height, z));

            angle += (360f / segments + 1);
        }
    }
```

For the move first to the Top I'm calling the AnimateCircle like this:

```
AnimateCircle(Top, Bottom);
```

And inside the AnimateCircle also Top, Bottom like this:

```
height = Mathf.Lerp(Top, Bottom, Mathf.PingPong(t, 1f));
```

In the switch case part `t = 0.5f` and `tGoal = 2f`

But instead moving first to the Top it's moving to the Bottom fast then from Bottom to Top.

But if I change `t = 1.5f` and `tGoal = 3f;` Then it will move first to the Top then from top to Bottom and that is fine. But 0.5 and 2 not moving it first up.

And if t = 1.5f and tGoal = 2f; it will move up to the Top and stop there.

But I can't find how to make the Bottom part so it will move to the Bottom first and stop or move first to the Bottom and move to Top.

Comment: Because maybe a new `DrawCircle` object is created?

Comment: In `AnimateCircle`, why do you have `if (height==Center)`? What happens if you get rid of that?

Comment: Also why is the `To` parameter unused?

Comment: @Ruzihm The reason I'm checking if height == Center is that only if the game start when the circle is in the Center then I want to move the circle slowly up or down to the Top or Bottom depending on what From is. And then after it moved to Top or to Bottom then to start a ping pong movement between Top and Bottom. If the game start when the enum state is not Center but Top or Bottom I want to start right away the ping pong between the Top and Bottom.

Comment: @Draco18s Still not in use. The reason is that I can't figure out how to make the ping pong between Top and Bottom after making first time once the part in the if (animStart) {} I'm doing this once the code in the animStart if it's Center then doing the ping pong after that but I'm not sure how to make the ping pong code.

Comment: Edited my question with unused code showing what I tried and explained what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Indeed I have another script manager script that there I'm creating a number of objects duplicating a prefab name DrawCircle. In this 5 objects. But after they all created I'm changing only one of them. While the game is running I set draw to true and then set animateCircle to true only on one of the objects.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Even if I generate only one object it's still set it to 0 move it back to the Center.

Comment: I can't figure it out the script is not Editor type but MonoBehaviour and still when I drag the script to a empty gameobject in the hierarchy and in the visual studio adding a breakpoint it stop at the breakpoint before I'm running the game. But it's MonoBehaviour type and no other objects using the script. So how come the script start before running the game ?

Comment: For example when I drag the script to a empty gameobject before running the game it stop on the line private float Center = 0; how can it be ? Then I make continue and it stop there again. What else can use or running the script ? I don't have any editor scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a float field called tGoal:

```
private float tGoal;
```

Set t depending on where you want it to start and tGoal on where you want it to stop animating. If you want it to start at `Center`, you have to determine the appropriate lerp value to start with:

```
        switch (circleheight)
        {
            case CircleHeight.Center:
                float centerT = Mathf.InverseLerp(Bottom, Top, Center);

                // t=0f+centerT, tGoal=1f to go to top first then stop at top
                // t=0f+centerT, tGoal=2f to go to top first then stop at bottom
                // t=2f-centerT, tGoal=2f to go to bottom first then stop at bottom
                // t=2f-centerT, tGoal=3f to go to bottom first then stop at top

                t = 2f - centerT; 
                tGoal = 3f;
                height = Center;
                break;
            case CircleHeight.Bottom:
                t= 0f;
                tGoal = 1f;
                height = Bottom;
                break;
            case CircleHeight.Top:
                t = 1f;
                tGoal = 2f;
                height = Top;
                break;
        }
```

Then use `Mathf.PingPong` to turn `t` into a lerp value that ping pongs. Stop when t equals tGoal, making sure tGoal never can exceed it:

```
private void AnimateCircle()
{
    if (animStart)
    {
        // prevent t from exceeding tGoal
        if (t > tGoal) {
            t = tGoal;
        }

        // end animation when t reaches goal
        if (t == tGoal) {
            animStart = false;
        }

        // advance height according to t
        height = Mathf.Lerp(Bottom, Top, Mathf.PingPong(t,1f));

        // advance height according to time & speed
        t += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I tried to do if (t == 0.6f)
    animStart = false; or tried if (t == Top) animateStart = false but it's never get to the animStart = false; another thing is when it's starting moving once from the center up it's moving fast like a small jump to the top then start the ping pong. Why it's not moving slow from the center to the top ?

Comment: @DubiDuboni You never put in a guarantee that t will ever equal those amounts exactly. You should should cap `t` so that it can't exceed the goal. I have edited my answer to provide an example of that.

Comment: It's not working for the bottom. It does for the top. For example I changed it now to t = 1.5f;
     tGoal = 3f; and calling AnimateCircle(Bottom, Top); and also inside AnimateCircle changed it Bottom to Top height = Mathf.Lerp(Bottom, Top, Mathf.PingPong(t, 1f)); but it's making a small jumping to the bottom from the center. For the Top first it's working finebut for the Bottom first it's not.

Comment: @DubiDuboni Please edit your question and add the code for `AnimateCircle` that you are using in that example.

Comment: I have edited my question now with the AnimateCircle code and the CreatePoints code and explained what I did and tried. I used different values of t and tGoal in the switch case then what you show to make it move first to the Top. I can't find how to make the Bottom part. And not sure why the values you showed are not working fine.

Comment: @DubiDuboni what happens if you reduce `animationSpeed` to a smaller number?  What happens when you increase ``tGoal` to `5`?

Comment: If I change the tGoal to 5 it's first moving up to Top then back to Bottom and back to Top 3 times. If I change the animationSpeed from 1 to 0.3f and tGoal still 5 it's just changing the speed make it slower movement.

Comment: In these comments you say `height = Mathf.Lerp(Bottom, Top, Mathf.PingPong(t, 1f))` but in the question you say `height = Mathf.Lerp(Top, Bottom, Mathf.PingPong(t, 1f));`. Which is it? It should be `height = Mathf.Lerp(Bottom, Top, Mathf.PingPong(t, 1f))` with `t=1.5f;` and `tGoal=3f;` like you said in your comment 8 hrs ago.

Comment: I checked it now again. When doing: height = Mathf.Lerp(Bottom, Top, Mathf.PingPong(t, 1f)) with t=1.5f; and tGoal=3f; First time it's jumping a bit up very small up then moving down to bottom then to the top. But it's first making a very small short jumping up. If I'm doing height = Mathf.Lerp(Top, Bottom, Mathf.PingPong(t, 1f)) with t=1.5f; and tGoal=3f; It will start moving up smooth slowly then down to bottom. The problem is when doing: Mathf.Lerp(Bottom, Top It's doing this small very small jump uo then move down.

Comment: @DubiDuboni Aha! Now I get it! It's because `Center` is not exactly halfway between `Bottom` and `Top`. You have to find out what is the proper lerp value for to position it at `Center`. I included it in my answer in `case CircleHeight.Center:`

Comment: Tested it now still making a small short jumping up before starting moving first down. I created a small short video clip showing the problem that's before you edited your answer but it's the same also now after the editing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTv2YBGVBKs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: In my code inside Start I did this two lines to fine bottom and top and then center is 0: Bottom = transform.InverseTransformPoint(renderer.bounds.min).y + 0.1f;
  Top = transform.InverseTransformPoint(renderer.bounds.max).y + 0.1f; Is it wrong to find the Top and Bottom ? I thought this way to find the Bottom top and Center for every object that have Renderer bounds.

Comment: @DubiDuboni okay, i think I found the issue! check `case CircleHeight.Center` in my answer again! It's not correct to always *add* `centerT`. If you're going down first you need to subtract it from the next `t` value for down.

Comment: Working great for the first going down. Thank you very much for the help.